# How can I put the average of the values of nested tuples inside a list into a new list?

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples, average

I have a list that looks like this, but much, much longer (1,000,000+ tuples):

```
[(1, (226, 242, 195)), (1, (218, 236, 188)), (1, (219, 235, 188)), (1, (220, 236, 187)), (1, (217, 235, 187)), (1, (216, 232, 185)), (1, (216, 234, 184))]
```

I want to find the average of each value in the nested tuple and move those into a new list, like this:

```
[[1, [avg of first values, avg of second values, avg of third values]]]
```

If possible, I also would want to get rid of the leading 1, and simplify the list to

```
[avg of first values, avg of second values, avg of third values]
```

I've looked through all similar questions, but none seem to have the exact answer I'm looking for.

The most common error is

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: The list name is r - here are all my attempts:

Comment: [sum(l)/len(l) for l in zip(*r)]

Comment: means = []   
for sublist in r:    
    means.append([sum(sublist)/len(sublist)])

Comment: r = [[sum(tup)/len(tup)] for tup in r]

Comment: r = [sum([sublst[0] for sublst in tup])/len(tup) for tup in r]

Comment: r = [[sum(i)/len(i)] for i in r]

Comment: Are there always three numbers in a tuple?

Comment: Think about what that `sum(tup)` is doing. It's trying to average the elements _inside_ each `tup`: that is, an integer and another tuple (of 3 elements). You can't add an integer to a tuple, and so can't average them. Hence the `TypeError`.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, there are always just three numbers (they are pixel RGB values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
>>> first_sum = second_sum = third_sum = 0
>>> for _, (first, second, third) in lst:
...     first_sum += first
...     second_sum += second
...     third_sum += third
...
>>> num = len(lst)
>>> [first_sum / num, second_sum / num, third_sum / num]
[218.85714285714286, 235.71428571428572, 187.71428571428572]
```

Comment: but, assuming there are always three numbers

Comment: @funnydman As far as the description of OP is concerned, such assumption is reasonable.

Comment: They are RGB values so yes there are always only 3

Answer (score 0):

In a single pass:

```
data  = [
    (1, (226, 242, 195)), 
    (1, (218, 236, 188)), 
    (1, (219, 235, 188)), 
    (1, (220, 236, 187)), 
    (1, (217, 235, 187)), 
    (1, (216, 232, 185)), 
    (1, (216, 234, 184))
    ]


first, second, third = 0, 0, 0
length = 0

for tup in data:
    first   +=  tup[1][0]
    second  +=  tup[1][1]
    third   +=  tup[1][2]
    length  +=  1


result = (first/length, second/length, third/length)
```